# typescript import *d.ts only instead of source code *.ts

Tags: typescript, import, reference, typescript-typings, tree-shaking

I prefer to do this trick because I want to import `a.d.ts` only for tree-shaking reasons. I need the type declaration only without source code. If I directly import source code `a.ts`, the tree-shaking for `a.ts` will not work.

Clearly, I counld use any as a dirty resolution, but I still want to have the benefit of type check with declaration files.

I refer to the Triple-Slash Directives, but it seems not my case.

Comment: So how is the corresponding implementation being loaded? Your imports can't have a .ts extension

Comment: Maybe I need a special `import` which is used for type check only and can be tree-shaking as no side effect, just like the prefix  `/*@__PURE__*/`

Comment: that exists. `import type`. But, if you are only using them as in type positions, the TS will automatically remove the import.